# MySQL - Group By difference in MySQL 5 to MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

i recently migrated my Database from MySql 5 to MySQL 8.
I installed a fresh new server with standard config and imported my data from the old database via sql import.

Now i have the problem, that my group by isn't working like before.

This is my SQL Select:

```
SELECT * from(SELECT A,B,C FROM table ORDER BY B DESC) AS temp GROUP BY C;
```

In MySQL 5 i get the value grouped by the first row of the inner select.

In MySQL 8 i get the value grouped by the last row  of the inner select. Even if i change the Order BY it has no effect.

Is this a server configuration? How can i change this without changing all my sql querys?

Best regards

Comment: I thought MySQL 8.0 finally rejected those invalid GROUP BY usages?

Comment: You shouldn 't use GROUP BY without aggregated functions

Comment: It was never 'working'; it just didn't error out. We can argue whether this was a feature or a bug. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem yesterday. Hope the following code can help you:)

`SELECT * from(SELECT A,B,C FROM table ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 10000) AS temp GROUP BY C;`